# ¿Cierro la conexión después de cada registro, o al cerrar el modulo?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, postgresql

tengo un software de punto de venta (POS) y en mi módulo de facturación realizo la respectiva conexión a la base de datos cada vez que voy a guardar una factura y una vez finalizado el guardado de la factura cierro la conexión.

eso lo hago así

```
for (i=0; i< cantidad_productos; i++){
    Connection con = null;
    con = DB_consultas_R_D.getConexion();
    PreparedStatement psql = null
    String SSQL = "INSERT INTO tabla (id,columna1,colmna2) values (1,'hola','mundo');"

    try {
        psql = con.prepareStatement(SSQL);
        psql.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar almacenar la información factura detallas:\n"
        + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    try {
    psql.close();
    con.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al intentar almacenar la información factura detallas:\n"
        + ex, "Error la cerrar conexion", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Metodo getConexion que me retorna una conexión a la base de datos.

```
public static Connection getConexion() {

    try {
        consulta_database_name(new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "/src/database_name.txt");
        consulta_database_ip(new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "/src/ip.txt");
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://" + ip + ":5432/" + database_name;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error en getConexion: "+e);
    }

    Connection cn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, contrasenia);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(e));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error de conexión a la base de datos:\n " + e);
    }
    return cn;
}
```

Entonces no se si así como lo hago está bien y que tan recomendable es dejar la conexión abierta todo el dia de trabajo.

actualmente cierro la conexion despues de guardar cada registro, ademas me presenta un poco de demora cuando guardo desde conexión de intranet.

Gracias

Comment: Yo, usando php y mysql, siempre cierro la conexion, sino, cuando tengo 2 conexiones abiertas, al enviar datos a la db, se me cuelga la pagina.

Comment: La pregunta es un poco amplia como está. Sin embargo, te puedo compartir que: a) abrir una conexión toma tiempo, así que abrirla y cerrarla es más lento que mantener la sesión iniciada; b) puedes usar un pool de conexiones como hikariCP o dbcp para que controle la disponibilidad de la conexión.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una cosa es abrir una conexión y otra crearla, y tu la estas creando para cada articulo que insertas. Eso no es correcto.
 Como dices, lo ideal es abrir y cerrar por cada operación que hagas. Pero si es un conjunto de operaciones relacionadas , no tiene sentido abrir y cerrar la conexión por cada articulo que vayas a insertar. Menos aun si estos proceso de insertado son consecutivos como por ejemplo en un bucle. Abres conexión, recorres todos los articulos vendidos en el ticket e insertando sus ventas y cierras la conexión.
 Si la operación de apertura y cierre es demasiado costosa, y penaliza en tu aplicación, la cual requiere tiempos rapidos de ejecución , estará en tu mano la decisión. Siempre utilizando la lógica, no abuses de aperturas y cierres, ni tampoco mantengas la conexión en toda la aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Sip, se cierra la conexion en cada metodo de una clase :) lo hiciste bien.
Al inicio crei que lo habias hecho mal porque supuse que el metodo de conexion lo habias creado en la clase donde crea slos metodos del crud.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Creo que si se trata de cantidades no excesivamente grandes de productos (en mis aplicaciones uso un umbral de 2500), deberías hacer todas las inserciones en una misma transacción. Es decir, crear una instrucción del tipo:

```
INSERT INTO tabla(id,columna1, columna2) VALUES
(1,'hola','mundo'),
(2,'col21','col22),
...
(n,'coln1','coln2');
```

Y entonces, o sea, después del bucle, abrir una conexión, ejecutar el update, y cerrarla.

Haciéndolo así te va a resultar mucho más ràpido. Pero recuerda, la diferencia más clara entre hacer un solo insert o n es que si falla el insert k, en el primer caso no se realiza ninguno de los anteriores a k, y haciendo n inserts se realizarían los k-1 anteriores al fallo.

En definitiva, hacerlo de una forma o de otra depende de la seguridad que tengas respecto a la corrección de los valores. Si sabes previamente que son correctos (por ejemplo en la restauración de un respaldo), entonces sin duda deberías usar una sola transacción.

Imagina lo de las conexiones exactamente igual que si fueran llamadas telefónicas. Intentar tener una llamada telefònica abierta durante más de una hora, por ejemplo, tiene sus peligros de que se corte. Por eso el umbral de 2500.

Por otro lado, desconozco las ventajas del PrepareStatement() pero creo que con lo que han evolucionado las conexiones, ya no tiene mucho sentido usarla. En mi caso realiza la operación con un executeUpdate(sql), siendo sql el string con el insert.